# Smooth Animation to Slide

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

I followed that tutorial to implement the basic setup of the ECSLidingViewController:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

Now I want to change the transition of opening the leftView like the Default Example of the TransitionFun example.

I added the following code to the leftView:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeSettings)];
[rightRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
```

Additionaly I added the line

```
[self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

After the first start of the app, the topview is following my fingers while opening/closing. But after choosing one point of the leftview tableview, it's not working anymore.

In all my topViews, I have the following code in the viewDidLoad method:

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openSettings:)];
leftRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
```

Can anybody tell me what to change, that the behaviour of the first start is all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry that was a stupid mistake:
I forgot to add

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

to each topViewController. Now it's working.